# Test a drag and drop user action in vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I want to test the user interaction of drap & drop on a DOM element.

Vue test utils provides the trigger method which accepts `eventType` (e.g. click) as parameter e.g. `wrapper.find('#someId').trigger('click')` but I can't find an eventType for drag&drop or moving an item.

The vue test utils documentation doesn't provide further details: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html

Is there any ways to trigger a drap &  drop action or combine several eventTypes to archive the same?

Answer (score 0):

to simulate a drag you can trigger this event on your wrapper :

```js
const wrapper = mount(App);

const scrollContainer = wrapper.find('[data-testid=scrollContainer]');
scrollContainer.trigger('mousedown');
scrollContainer.trigger('mousemove');
scrollContainer.trigger('mouseup');
```